# Why doesn't the optimizer eliminate High in a loop?

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

People said that Delphi produces quite-nice optimized code on integer operations. I try the following example in Delphi 2007, and see its assembly code produced by the compiler.

```
program p1000;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

procedure test;
var
  arr: array of integer;
  i: integer;

begin
  SetLength(arr, 100);
  for i := 0 to High(arr) do
  begin
    if (i = High(arr)) then
    begin
      arr[i] := -9;
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
  test;
  readln;
end.
```

When building configuration is set to DEBUG, I can set a breakpoint and use shortkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to see its assembly code, like this:

```
Project3.dpr.11: for i := 0 to High(arr) do
004045A1 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
004045A4 E8F7FAFFFF       call @DynArrayHigh
004045A9 8BF0             mov esi,eax
004045AB 85F6             test esi,esi
004045AD 7C1D             jl $004045cc
004045AF 46               inc esi
004045B0 33DB             xor ebx,ebx
Project3.dpr.13: if (i = High(arr)) then
004045B2 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
004045B5 E8E6FAFFFF       **call @DynArrayHigh**
004045BA 3BD8             cmp ebx,eax
004045BC 750A             jnz $004045c8
Project3.dpr.15: arr[i] := -9;
004045BE 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
004045C1 C70498F7FFFFFF   mov [eax+ebx*4],$fffffff7
Project3.dpr.17: end;
004045C8 43               inc ebx
Project3.dpr.11: for i := 0 to High(arr) do
004045C9 4E               dec esi
004045CA 75E6             jnz $004045b2
```

As far as I can understand, it calls `High()` function again and again in the loop:

```
Project3.dpr.13: if (i = High(arr)) then
    004045B2 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
    004045B5 E8E6FAFFFF       **call @DynArrayHigh**
    004045BA 3BD8             cmp ebx,eax
```

When building configuration is set to RELEASE, the breakpoint isn't available, so I press <kbd>F8</kbd>/<kbd>F7</kbd> to step into the loop.

```
00404589 6A64             push $64
0040458B 8D45FC           lea eax,[ebp-$04]
0040458E B901000000       mov ecx,$00000001
00404593 8B1554454000     mov edx,[$00404554]
00404599 E8B6FCFFFF       call @DynArraySetLength
0040459E 83C404           add esp,$04
004045A1 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
004045A4 E8F7FAFFFF       call @DynArrayHigh
004045A9 8BF0             mov esi,eax
004045AB 85F6             test esi,esi
004045AD 7C1D             jl $004045cc
004045AF 46               inc esi
004045B0 33DB             xor ebx,ebx
004045B2 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
004045B5 E8E6FAFFFF       call @DynArrayHigh
004045BA 3BD8             cmp ebx,eax
004045BC 750A             jnz $004045c8
004045BE 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
004045C1 C70498F7FFFFFF   mov [eax+ebx*4],$fffffff7
004045C8 43               inc ebx
004045C9 4E               dec esi
004045CA 75E6             jnz $004045b2
004045CC 33C0             xor eax,eax
004045BC 750A             jnz $004045c8
```

Again, the same `call @DynArrayHigh` is produced...
So my question is, why the compiler can't optimize this? simply save the `High()` value in a local register/variable because the array size is not changed.

Comment: It's not changed in *this* thread, but the compiler has no way of knowing if it's changed from another thread - I guess there's only so much it can check before optimising safely.

Comment: but the 'arr' is a local array, so the other threads can't possibly change it.

Comment: @roger, that array is a local variable, so it should be simply recognizable.

Comment: You can see in that code that what you say is true, my point is that the compiler has to evaluate how/when that local variable can be changed. I'm just suggesting that it doesn't check deeply enough and just assumes that because the array is dynamic, it's possible that it changes.

Comment: if you make a procedure call: `procedure( var anArr : array of integer);` the optimization works much better.

Comment: Does the compiler knows about the `High` function?

Comment: @LURD I tried passing the arr as a parameter, but still, it produces call to High() in the loop.

Comment: Yes, the High function is interpreted as DynArrayHigh which returns the upper bound of the dynamic array.

Comment: @DoctorLai, in XE3 there is no call to High in the loop. The High value is passed in a register in the procedure call. (Or on the stack if more than three parameters is to be passed in the procedure).

Comment: I don't get it. how can the compiler predict if the length of the dynamic array is/isn't changed in run time?

Comment: @LURD ok, in this case, I have to get the latest Delphi.

Comment: @kobik, if it would evaluate all the function calls inside the loop and check if there's a `SetLength` call for that array. If not, then it might treat that `High` bound as a *constant* value.

Comment: @TLama, I don't think this is practical. consider a call to another function passing the array by reference which changes the array length. or changing array length without use of explicit `SetLenth`, or re-initializing the array. in fact I would be surprised if the compiler *did* "optimize" this.

Comment: @kobik, that's the answer, it doesn't! By design...

Comment: The compiler obviously knows about the function, @Leonardo, or it wouldn't have translated `High` into `@DynArrayHigh`. It's a compiler-magic function.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, I know that, but the question asked is why the compiler calls `High` again and again in the line: `if (i = High(arr)) then`.

Comment: @Lurd, the procedure you've defined receives an *open array*, not a dynamic array. I'm pretty sure open arrays' lengths cannot be modified. An open array's length has always been passed as a second parameter; that's not new in XE3. Since it's not a dynamic array, it's clear why the compiler doesn't call `@DynArrayHigh` for it. Instead, the compiler reads the value of the parameter, which is the only place the `High` value for that open array is stored.

Comment: @Kobik, a compiler predicts whether the length changes through *data-flow analysis*. It's an entire field of computer science, and it's not trivial to do, in general. Even harder is *inter-procedural* data-flow analysis, which is what the compiler would have to do to determine that the memory `arr` points to is not modified by a called procedure. Embarcadero *could* choose to grant the compiler special knowledge about certain intrinsic functions (like `@DynArrayHigh`), thereby allowing it to know that calls to it don't affect subsequent calls to the same function, but that's a slippery slope.

Comment: @RobKennedy, passing an open array was a suggestion to eliminate the the function call in the loop. I don't know why D2007 still would call a function to get the length in the loop in that case though (as mentioned by DoctorLai in a comment).

Comment: Please refrain from extended discussion in comments. If you have an answer, please post it as such. If you have gotten clarification, then the comment is no longer needed (especially if the question is edited to include clarifying information).  If there's anything you want to save that answers the question, put it into an answer. I'll probably purge these comments later today.

Comment: @RobKennedy - what I meant to ask was if the compiler knows what the function does. Some compilers treat some special functions differently, for example, `sizeof` (which is actually an operator.) That was my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a answer but rather a (self destructing) comment :)

In my view, The compiler must not attempt to optimize this.

Why should the compiler attempt to optimize a (non-deterministic) `High` function as opposed to other? (such as `Length`)

The *dynamic* array length might be changed inside the loop either by `SetLenth`, or by other means. the array might be re-initilzed at run-time and your code might depend on that:

```
for i := 0 to High(arr) do
begin
  if (i = High(arr)) then
    arr[i] := -9
  else
    if foo() then
      arr := nil; // or SetLength(arr, 0);

  if High(arr) = -1 then Exit; // arr is nil  
end;
```

How do you suggest this should be optimized? Should the compiler even attempt to optimized this?
I don't see anything *special* about `High` functionm even if the compiler translates it to `@DynArrayHigh`.

If you want your code to be optimized , optimize it *yourself* .e.g:

```
var
  arrHigh: Integer;

  arrHigh := High(arr);
  for i := 0 to arrHigh do
    if i = arrHigh then...
```

Comment: thanks.. i agree. just wonder maybe the compiler is clever enough to figure it out. :)